# mvc edit return value but db doesnt update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i have mvc project to register new student and give him courses and degree,etc, as shown in the database(i use entity framework) [database of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Ujn.png)
. the edit view code is :

```
@model IList<HighStudy.Models.Grade>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title" align="center">Student Info</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <p>Name: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[0].Student.Name)</p>
                        <p>Level: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[0].Student.Level)</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <p>Department: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[0].Student.Department)</p>
                        <p>Study Type: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[0].Student.StudyType)</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title" align="center">Course 1</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                            { 
                                if (Model[i].CourseNumber == 1)
                                {
                                    if (Model[i].Mark == "A" || Model[i].Mark == "B")
                                    {
                                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                    @Model[i].Cours.Course_Title
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Cours.Course_Title, new { style = "width:50%" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Cours.Course_Title)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                    @Model[i].Grade1
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Grade1, new { style = "width:30px" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Grade1)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                    @Model[i].Mark
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Mark, new { style = "width:30px" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Mark)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                        @Model[i].Cours.Course_Title
                                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Cours.Course_Title, new { style = "width:50%" })
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Cours.Course_Title)
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                        @Model[i].Grade1
                                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Grade1, new { style = "width:30px" })
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Grade1)
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                        @Model[i].Mark
                                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Mark, new { style = "width:30px" })
                                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Mark)
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title" align="center">Course 2</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <ul class="list-group">
                            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                            {
                                if (Model[i].CourseNumber == 2)
                                {
                                    if (Model[i].Mark == "A" || Model[i].Mark == "B")
                                    {
                                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                    @Model[i].Cours.Course_Title
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Cours.Course_Title, new { style = "width:50%" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Cours.Course_Title)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                    @Model[i].Grade1
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Grade1, new { style = "width:30px" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Grade1)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                    @Model[i].Mark
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Mark, new { style = "width:30px" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Mark)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                    @Model[i].Cours.Course_Title
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Cours.Course_Title, new { style = "width:50%" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Cours.Course_Title)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                    @Model[i].Grade1
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Grade1, new { style = "width:30px" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Grade1)
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="col-lg-2">
                                                    @Model[i].Mark
                                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model[i].Mark, new { style = "width:30px" })
                                                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model[i].Mark)
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
}

<div class="col-lg-offset-0">
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

and in the controller code for the edit view is :
[edit view code in the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4bly.png)
. when it reach `db.Entry(g).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;`

it goes to catch block!!

any help will be useful, thanks in advance.

Comment: what exception is it?

Comment: the execption is "The entity type List`1 is not part of the model for the current context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED** 
my current exception was :

### ( Unable to update the EntitySet - because it has a DefiningQuery and no  element exists in the  element to support the current operation

steps that solve it :

- delete all duplicate @html.hiddenfor(model=> model.StudentID) in the edit view
- Right click on .edmx file and chose open with xml editor
- search for DefiningQuery and Remove it, yes Remove it
- search for ( store:Schema="dbo" ) and rename it to ( Schema="dbo" )

  ---

  these were the steps that saved my life, thank you all my friends for help, i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should iterate over your collection to add each object to the context, and set it to Modified.

```
foreach(grade in g)
{
    db.Entry(grade).State = EntityState.Modified;   
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

You must do `SaveChanges` outside the foreach statement

Comment: i did and the first iterate goes fine but the second throw an exception ,, i will write it in the next comment

Comment: "Attaching an entity of type 'HighStudy.Models.Student' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate."

Comment: I believe this is the right answer, but you also need to add a hidden field for each grade inside the View .. the hidden field shall has the value of the grade ID ... it should be smthg like this @Html.HiddenFor(item=>item.ID)

Comment: thnks for answer my friend , i did, but it keeps doing the same, in the first iterate it goes well, but in the second it throw the same exception in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Entry(g).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
```

In the above code you are getting `g` from another object, you need to originate it from the same `db` object which you are using to change the `State`

another things could be the `list`, I think  `state` of  `List` can't be modified altogether.

consider doing something like this

```
        foreach (var item in g)
                {
                    db.Set<Grade>().Attach(item);
                    db.Entry<Grade>(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
```

Recently gone through the same error, and foreach saved my life. Not sure if its a very clean way to do it.

Comment: thanks for your answer my friend, well i didnt know what is <tblInsuredDetail> so i used <Grade> instead and it goes well for the first iterate in the foreach loop, but in the second iterate it throw exception as in the next comment

Comment: "Attaching an entity of type 'HighStudy.Models.Student' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate."

Comment: The error is clear, you have some duplicate keys while in update, kindly provide some more code.

Comment: that was right, i was having duplicate @html.HiddenFor(model=>model.studentID) . i deleted them and now it goes well in the foreach loop but the db.savechanges() throw an exception : "Unable to update the EntitySet 'Grades' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <UpdateFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.", any additional code you want me to post just ask for it. thanks for kindness my friend

Comment: and i should mention that i have a composite primary key in the grades table, if that matter. you can see the database in the photo above